# Quickly bump up the text size on iPython Notebook generated reveal.js slides

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, reveal.js

Problem: I'm standing in front of a class and presenting using reveal.js slides generated from an iPython notebook. Someone mentions that the text size is too small, and ask if I can zoom in a bit. Ctrl-+ for zooming doesn't seem to work (anymore? I want to remember that I've done it before in Chrome).

What should I do in this situation? Stopping the presentation and start fiddling with CSS doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Indeed, in the CSS you can search for ``zoom:`` and change the value to i.e. ``zoom: 1.4;``. I would enjoy hearing a better solution as well.

Comment: any updates on this question?